# Что или о том, что?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Её муж иногда рассказывал ей, что она натворила накануне.*

*Её муж иногда рассказывал ей о том, что она натворила накануне.*

Какой вариант верный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верен второй вариант (так я думал вначале, см. продолжение ответа). Первый подойдёт в следующем случае:

*Её муж как-то рассказал ей, что её подруга натворила накануне массу глупостей.*

Как видно, в этом случае хоть немного раскрывается, что именно она натворила.

Прошу прощения за столь однозначный ответ, но теперь я понял, что и без *о том* вполне правильно. Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*Я вспомнил про Антипа и рассказал ему, что видел.* [И. С. Тургенев. Бурмистр (1847)]

*И он рассказал ему, что здесь написано.* [И. А. Гончаров. Обломов (1859)]

*Он думал, что казенные крестьяне отправляют барщиной свою подать, расспрашивал о сельской общине, о помещичьей власти; я рассказал ему, что знал.* [А. И. Герцен. Былое и думы. Часть шестая. Англия (1864)]

Таким образом, можно говорить ***и так и так.*** В первом случае акцент именно на ***содержании*** того, что она натворила, а во втором речь может идти как о содержании, так и о вещах, связанных с ним. По крайней мере, мне так видится это.

Верно заметил oleedd, что предложение ***какое-то странное.*** С чего бы он ей рассказывал про неё же саму, она что, сама не помнит или напилась настолько?)) Поэтому изменю свой пример.

Comment: Эххх, хотел я вас поправить, да пока размышлял... ))) Мне остается только добавить, что вариант "рассказать, что" можно трактовать двояко с точки зрения грамматики. Сравните: "рассказал, что [именно] видел" и "рассказал, что [действительно] видел (что-то понятное из контекста)".

Comment: Вот эта неоднозначность грамматики позволяет привести похожие примеры, когда вариант без "о том", едва ли не единственный возможный. ***"Свидетель показал, что не был знаком с потерпевшим".*** "...О том, что..." - выглядело бы тут совершеннейшим канцеляритом и косноязычием.

Comment: *Эххх, хотел я вас поправить, да пока размышлял... )))* — Хе-хе))) Точно, *что **именно** видел* и *что **действительно** видел,* так и есть!)

Comment: Мысль уловил. Но ведь не рассказывают кому-то, что он натворил массу глупостей, а говорят об этом. Если рассказывать, то кому-то третьему. Или у неё амнезия, тогда ей можно рассказать.

Comment: И правда ерунда получается, спасибо! Дописал и подправил ответ.

Comment: Впервые соглашаешься с критикой)

Comment: Да ладно впервые))) Серьёзно?

Comment: Не помню такого, всегда выступаешь резко против. Имею в виду мою критику.

Comment: Моя знакомая как-то нажала несколько клавиш на клавиатуре, не понимая, что делает. Я потом помогал исправить последствия и _рассказывал ей, что она натворила_. В жизни на каждом шагу кто-то что-то делает, не осознавая последствий — для этого не обязательно напиваться до беспамятства. А даже если она напилась до беспамятства, это может противоречить только нормам этики, ЗОЖ и т.п., но не нормам же стилистики/грамматики.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Вначале&all=x

Comment: Отличный пример, grizzly, согласен! Слава, боялся ошибиться со слитным написанием, как раньше, оказалось, зря, спасибо! Oleedd, тем не менее начальный пример с кануном остаётся чересчур натянутым, нереальным. Хорош стирать комментарии.

Comment: Артём, в примере про массу глупостей ещё вот что интересно: там речь о факте, о нём один раз рассказывают, а если иногда (несколько раз), то говорят. То есть это: *Её муж иногда говорил (не "рассказывал") ей, что она натворила накануне массу глупостей.* Или у неё провалы в памяти, и он рассказывал (сообщал) ей заново.

Comment: Пример про крестьян интересный: только там подставляется не "о том", а "то".

Comment: *По крайней мере мне так видится это* — а здесь точно значение "как минимум"? Просто лучше подходит "во всяком случае", а тогда запятая нужна.

Comment: Не согласен про крестьян, думаю, что там "о том" больше подходит. Да, поставлю запятую, спасибо.

Comment: Во всяком случае, там "то" тоже подходит, а в других — нет.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение не прозрачное для восприятия, нужны такие логические ударения:
*Её муж иногда расскАзывал ей, чтО она натворила накануне.*

Местоимения можно пропускать (как и в примере из вопроса):
*Рассказал (о том), как сдал экзамен.

Рассказал ему (о том), что здесь написано.

Рассказал ему (про то), что видел.*

Здесь вопрос звучания: как больше нравится. В вашем примере с местоимением звучит плавнее, понятнее, доступнее.

*Я вспомнил про Антипа и рассказал ему, что видел.* || Союзное слово. Как и в предложении из вопроса.
*Рассказал (о том), что видел русалку.* || Союз.

Чем короче придаточное, тем уместнее пропуск. Если в придаточном одно слово, то с местоимением обычно не очень звучит. В вашем примере придаточное не самое краткое и без пропуска всё же лучше.

*Иногда рассказывал* — обычно рассказывают сказки и т.п., а какие-то сведения — один раз. Звучит так, что она натворила столько всего, что можно несколько дней рассказывать. Это не реалистично. А если рассказывал одно и то же — то правильнее "напоминал".